# Target location appearing blank when setting it to a php file in html

Tags: php, html

I had a basic form which accepts username and password and then directs it to file.php. Where i compare and the username and password to ones already in the password.txt.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>Authentication</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="signin text-center">
        <form action="file.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form">Username:
            <input type="text" name="username"></div>

            <div class="form">Password:
            <input type="Password" name="password"></div>

            <input type="submit" value="Go">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Password test, page 2</title>
  <head>


  <body>

      <?php 
         $name  = $_POST['username'];
         $pass  = $_POST['password']; 

       //read the contents of our password file.
         $myFile = "password.txt";
         $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
         $data = fgets($fh);
         fclose($fh);

         //echo the data from the text file
         echo $data;

         //print out an HTML line break
         print "<br>";

         //now we need to split our line of data from the text
         //file so that we can do the comparison.

         //split the text into an array
         $text = explode(":",$data);


         //echo the split user name
         echo $text[0];

         //print out an HTML line break
         print "<br>";

         //echo the split password
         echo $text[1];

         //assign the data to variables
         $good_name = $text[0];
         $good_pass = $text[1];

        //print the variables
        echo $good_name;
        echo $good_pass;

         //print out an HTML line break
         print "<br>";

         //compare the strings
         if($name === $good_name && $pass === $good_pass){
            echo "That is the correct log-in information";
         }else{
            echo "That is not the correct log-in information.";
         } 
      ?>    
        <br> 

  </body>
</html>
```

password.txt contains 
        a:k

When I enter username as a and password as k, it gives me false output, i.e, login incorrect. However if i remove the condition to check for password, it gives me correct login.

I thought maybe the password in the form is encrypted and thus can't compare it with a string. But I think, HTML forms don't encrypt passwords.

Also I'm hosting this site from my computer.

Will be grateful for any help. Thanks

Comment: I hope you're not intending on going live with this at some point in time.

Comment: You should also be providing an example of what `password.txt` contains.

Comment: Not going live. My site otherwise consists of nothing right now. password.text contains a simple line     a:k      That's it.

Comment: Ok. Well, someone provided you with an answer below; see that. If that still doesn't work, then you'll need to tell them.

Comment: Btw, plain text does not equal md5 so your match checking will not happen.

Comment: Yeah I edited it out now. It still does not work. Infact as soon as i put md5 anywhere, my php file turns blank in the browser. after that it never returns to proper state even when md5 is removed. I have to shift the contents to different php.file then

Answer (score 1):

You are doing md5 on the wrong one. 
You should have your password saved as md5 string in your file and when You recive via POST you should do `md5($_POST['pass'])`. Compare it and it should be ok. If not make sure You remove whitespaces and new line sign with `trim()`.

Example:

```
<?php 
         $name  = $_POST['username'];
         $pass  = md5($_POST['password']); // add md5 here 

         //assign the data to variables
         $good_name = $text[0];
         $good_pass = $text[1]; // remove md5 here as it should be already encoded with it
     // ...

         //compare the strings
         if($name === $good_name && $pass === $good_pass){
            echo "That is the correct log-in information";
         }else{
            echo "That is not the correct log-in information.";
         }
```

**Edit #1**:
Example of txt file:

```
admin:21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3
```

Password is: `admin`

Comment: Since text[1] is a simple text, not md5 encrypted as I myself put it there. So basically, good_name should be a plain text, pass is a plain text. I am confused where am i going wrong. Because even if remove md5 from everywhere, it still does not work the way i want it to.

Comment: @AkritiAnand it is cuz You do not understand why you should use md5. You should have encoded password saved in your text file. I will add an edit in a min with example of txt file.

Comment: Okay, so suppose I don't want this to be encrypted. I want to compare plain text only. What is in this password field of the form which does not allow this? I am sorry if this is a bit silly as I am new to this.

Comment: @AkritiAnand If you don't want to compare encoded strings, just the plain text then remove all `md5` from your code and make sure the string you are reading from file does not contain any white spaces or new line signs (use `trim` to remove them).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution was rather simple and my mistake is rather embarrassing. I made a typo while writing type of the password input field. It should be 'password' and not 'Password'. Now it works. Thank you everyone for helping.